# PHP Script will not insert into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing this code and have it working well so far.  Basically, it is the phpacademy OOP Login script that I am modifying for my own uses.  The part I'm having issues with is

```
$user->update(array(
                    'username' => input::get('username'),
                    'name' => input::get('name'),
                    'address' => input::get('address'),
                    'group' => input::get('group'),
                    'hire_date' => input::get('hire_date'),
                    ), $user->findUser(input::get('username'), 'id'));
```

It will work great if I remove the `group` line out of it, but with `group` in, it just doesn't work.  I do have the group as a column in my mysql database so I'm not sure where to go from here.  Still kind of new to this, but learning a lot.  I would appreciate the help anybody can give me.

The update user page

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';
$user = new user();
$db = db::getInstance();
if($user->data()->group > 1) {
    session::flash('home', "You do not have permission to view this page");
    redirect::to('home.php');
}
if(!$user->isloggedin()) {
    redirect::to('index.php');
}
if(input::exists()) {
    if(token::check(input::get('token'))){
        $validate = new validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'username' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 2
            ),
            'name' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 2,
                'max' => 50
            ),
            'hire_date' => array(
                'required' => true,
            ),
            'address' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'max' => 100
            ),
            'group' => array(
                'required' => true,
            )
        ));
        if($validation->passed()) {
            try {
                $user->update(array(
                    'username' => input::get('username'),
                    'name' => input::get('name'),
                    'address' => input::get('address'),
                    'group' => input::get('group'),
                    'hire_date' => input::get('hire_date'),
                    ), $user->findUser(input::get('username'), 'id'));
                session::flash('home', 'the details have been updated');
                redirect::to('home.php');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            foreach($validation->errors() as $error){
                echo $error, '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
<head>
    <title>PCTSoft V1.0</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body class="main">
    <form action="" method="post" class="register">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" value="" id="username" name="username"><br>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo escape($user->findUser(input::get('username'), 'name'));?>" id="name" name="name"><br>
            <label for="hire_date">Hire Date</label>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo escape($user->findUser(input::get('username'), 'hire_date'));?>" id="hire_date" name="hire_date" placeholder="2014-01-01"><br>
            <label for="address">Address</label>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo escape($user->findUser(input::get('username'), 'address'));?>" id="address" name="address" style="width:300px;"><br>
            <label for="group">Group</label>
            <input type="text" id="group" name="group" value="<?php echo escape($user->findUser(input::get('username'), 'group'));?>"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Update">
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo token::generate();?>">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

The `user` class

```
<?php
class user {
    private $_db,
            $_data,
            $_sessionName,
            $_cookieName,
            $_isloggedin;

    public function __construct($user = null) {
        $this->_db = db::getInstance();
        $this->_sessionName = config::get('session/session_name');
        $this->_cookieName = config::get('remember/cookie_name');
        if(!$user) {
            if(session::exists($this->_sessionName)) {
                $user = session::get($this->_sessionName);
                if($this->find($user)) {
                    $this->_isloggedin = true;
                } else {
                    $this->logout();
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->find($user);
        }
    }
    public function update($fields, $id = null) {
        if(!$id && $this->isloggedin()) {
            $id = $this->data()->id;
        }
        if(!$this->_db->update('users', $id, $fields)) {
            throw new Exception('there was a problem updating the information');
        }
    }
    public function create($fields = array()) {
        if(!$this->_db->insert('users', $fields)) {
            throw new Exception('There was a problem creating an account');
        }
    }
    public function findUser($user = null, $column) {
        if($user) {
            $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
            $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));
            if($data->count()) {
                $this->_data = $data->first();
                return $this->data()->$column;
            }
        }
    }
    public function find($user = null) {
        if($user) {
            $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
            $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));
            if($data->count()) {
                $this->_data = $data->first();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    public function login($username = null, $password = null, $remember = false) {

        if(!$username && !$password && $this->exists()) {
            session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
        } else {
        $user = $this->find($username);
        if($user) {
            if($this->data()->password === hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)) {
                session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
                if($remember) {
                    $hash = hash::unique();
                    $hashCheck = $this->_db->get('users_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));
                    if(!$hashCheck->count()) {
                        $this->_db->insert('users_session', array(
                            'user_id' => $this->data()->id,
                            'hash' => $hash
                        ));
                    } else {
                        $hash = $hashCheck->first()->hash;
                    }
                    cookie::put($this->_cookieName, $hash, config::get('remember/cookie_expiry'));
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
    public function exists() {
        return (!empty($this->_data)) ? true : false;
    }
    public function logout() {
        $this->_db->delete('users_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));
        session::delete($this->_sessionName);
        cookie::delete($this->_cookieName);
    }
    public function data() {
        return $this->_data;
    }
    public function isloggedin() {
        return $this->_isloggedin;
    }
}
```

The `db` class

```
<?php
class db {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo,
            $_query,
            $_error = false,
            $_results,
            $_count = 0;
    private function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . config::get('mysql/db'),config::get('mysql/username'),config::get('mysql/password'));
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            die($ex->getMessage());
        }
    }    
    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new db();           
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
    public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
        $this->_error = false;
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            $x = 1;
            if(count($params)) {
                foreach($params as $param) {
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
                }
            }
            if($this->_query->execute()) {
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
            } else {
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
    public function action($action, $table, $where = array() ) {
        if(count($where) === 3) {
            $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');
            $field      = $where[0];
            $operator   = $where[1];
            $value      = $where[2];

            if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
                $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";
                if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                    return $this;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }    
    public function get($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
    }
    public function delete($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('DELETE', $table, $where);
    }    
    public function insert($table, $fields = array()) {
        $keys = array_keys($fields);
        $values = '';
        $x=1;
        foreach($fields as $field) {
            $values .= "?";
            if($x < count($fields)) {
                $values .= ', ';
            }
            $x++;
        }
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values})";
        if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }    
    public function update($table, $id, $fields = array()) {
        $set = '';
        $x = 1;
        foreach($fields as $name => $value) {
            $set .= "{$name} = ?";
            if($x < count($fields)) {
                $set .= ',';
            }
            $x++;
        }
        $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE id = {$id}";

        if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }    
    public function results() {
        return $this->_results;
    }    
    public function first() {
        $return = $this->results();
        return $return[0];
    }    
    public function error() {
        return $this->_error;
    }    
    public function count() {
        return $this->_count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages? What have you tried so far?

Comment: maybe it should not be called `group`, maybe this generates a conflict with `GROUP` from `GROUP BY` statement.

Comment: I do not get the down votes by the way.
There is for sure a lot of code, but it helps to solve the problem. But a little more debugging in the beginning should have been done, before the question was posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, you cannot name a column "Group" since it is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).  Rename the column to something more specific to your code, like userGroup.

Comment: I knew it was going to be something simple.  Interestingly enough, my register portion of the script worked just fine with the column named group.  Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

As @DanFromGermany pointed out, there is for sure a problem with escaping of the database table columns.

```
class Db {
  public function update($table, $id, $fields = array()) {
    $set = '';
    $x = 1;
    foreach($fields as $name => $value) {
      $set .= "`{$name}` = ?"; // Mind this row. ` were added to table column name.
      if($x < count($fields)) {
        $set .= ',';
      }
      $x++;
    }
    $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE id = {$id}";

    if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Also you should read up on [PDOStatement::errorInfo()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php).
It would have reported that error. ;)

Please vote @DanFromGermany s comment up, if this is really this answer helps you out.

By the way: Class names should be always starting with a capital letter. Preferably continuing in [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)